# XSD with no order and selective restriction

Tags: xsd

I need to validate an XML that contains element in random order and some of them must exist and some of them only once. BTW some elements can be nested recursively.

For example there is a room that should contain one door and any number of boxes and elements. Boxes Can contain other boxes or/and elements.

Example XML:

```
<Room>
    <Element />
    <Box>
        <Box>
            <Element />
            <Box></Box>
            <Element />
        </Box>
        <Element />
    </Box>
    <Door />
    <Element />
</Room>
```

This example is very simple, but in my case there are a lot of elements that can be in `<Room>`. Recursion is not a problem. The problem is to make `<Door>` to be required and in any order with siblings that are not required.

**UPD**: the question is about XSD 1.0 because I use .NET and there are no free lib for XSD 1.1

Answer (score 0):

From what i'm reading i think you might need to use schema (XSD) indicators.

Check following link for more information: [Schema indicators](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp)

### ***Random Order***

*From your question:*

> I need to validate an XML that contains element in random order

*Possible answer:*

Using the All indicator (see [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp)) you can specify that the element are in random order.

> All Indicator
>
> The  indicator specifies that the child elements can appear in any order, and that each child element must occur only once:

### ***Occurances***

*From your question:*

> some of them must exist and some of then once

*Possible answer:*

If i'm understanding it correctly you want to specify the amount of times an element exist or can be used. This is called occurance and again can be found back on the following [link](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp). You'll have to determine minOccurs and maxOccurs following your requirements.

> Occurrence Indicators
>
> Occurrence indicators are used to define how often an element can occur.
>
> The "maxOccurs" indicator specifies the maximum number of times an element can occur:
>
> The "minOccurs" indicator specifies the minimum number of times an element can occur:

Everything including examples can be found back on the [XSD/Schema indicators](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp).

### ***How your XSD (xml schema) will probably look like:***

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="Room" type="Room_T"/>

  <xs:complexType name="Room_T">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="Element" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="Box" type="Box_T" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="Door" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:complexType name="Box_T">
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="Element" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="Box" type="Box_T" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I didn't check if the code above is valid but i think it could definitely get you started!

Comment: Yes, you are right about indicators, but the thing that bothers is that "The {max Occurs} Of An Element In An 'all' Model Group Must Be 0 Or 1. The Value 'unbounded' For Element 'Element' Is Invalid."

Comment: From my point of view the .xsd is fine. Could you point out to me when you're receiving that warning?
Quote:"The value 'unbounded' for Element 'Element is Invalid."

Comment: Any online xml validators will return this error for this xml+xsd. Now I've found out that xsd of 1.1 version allows any value for "maxOccurs" attribute of "all" elements indicator. But unfortunately there are no free library for .NET which I use. I'll clarify the question